# How to set multiple routes files under the same subdomain in express-subdomain

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-subdomain

I'm using `express-subdomain` to redirect routes to api subdomain.
I've two route's files: `auth.routes.js` and `utils.routes.js`.  I wanna that both route files are available under the subdomain `api`. I tried the pass an index file that is importing both of them, but it is not working. How can i do?

```js
index.js
const authRouter = require("./auth.routes");
const utilsRouter = require("./utils.router");

module.exports = {
    authRouter,
    utilsRouter,
};


app.js
var apiRouter = require("./routes/testing/index");
app.use(subdomain("api", apiRouter));
```

Comment: `but it is not working` - do you get errors? have you read [this issue](https://github.com/bmullan91/express-subdomain/issues/17) (if applicable)

Comment: @JaromandaX i don't see a connection with my issue. I want to use multiple routes files under the same subdomain. I could try this way: `app.use(subdomain("api", authRouter )); app.use(subdomain("api", utilsRouter ));` but on the second row i'm getting this error: `The second parameter must be a function that handles fn(req, res, next) params.`

Comment: as I said **if applicable** - i.e. *multi-level TLD* - you never said WHAT the error/issue was, just "it doesn't work"

Comment: ahh, in that case the issue is that you're passing an invalid parameter - as the error states - so, something in `utilsRouter` is wrong. compared to `authRouter`

Comment: hey @JaromandaX, don't know if you down voted my question but just wanna clarify that i didn't meant to be rude in my second comment. In fact, erroneously i sent only the first row of my comment and while i was editing it i figured out that after 5 minutes you can't edit anymore.

Comment: No, I didn't downvote

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get it working.

**This is what i tried but didn't work:**

1. Import both routing files in `index.js`.

   `index.js`

   ```
   const authRouter = require("./auth.routes");
   const utilsRouter = require("./utils.routes");

   module.exports = {authRouter, utilsRouter}
   ```

   `app.js`

   ```
   var apiRoutes = require("./routes/index");

   app.use(subdomain("api", apiRoutes));
   ```

   This will return the following error in any circumstance: `Error: The second parameter must be a function that handles fn(req, res, next) params.`
2. Create two different instances of express-subdomain

   `app.js`

   ```
   var authRouter = require("./routes/auth.routes");
   var utilsRouter = require("./routes/utils.routes");

   app.use(subdomain("api", authRouter));
   app.use(subdomain("api", utilsRouter));
   ```

   In this scenario the second instance will be ignored, so all requests will go through `authRouter` and none will reach `utilsRouter`.

**This is what worked:**

I thought, let me print the content of `authRouters` and `utilsRouter` objects.
They differ only for the content of the `stack` list:

```
[Function: router] {
  params: {},
  _params: [],
  caseSensitive: undefined,
  mergeParams: undefined,
  strict: undefined,
  stack: [
    Layer {
      handle: [Function: bound dispatch],
      name: 'bound dispatch',
      params: undefined,
      path: undefined,
      keys: [],
      regexp: /^\/auth\/signup\/?$/i,
      route: [Route]
    },
    Layer {
      handle: [Function: bound dispatch],
      name: 'bound dispatch',
      params: undefined,
      path: undefined,
      keys: [],
      regexp: /^\/auth\/signin\/?$/i,
      route: [Route]
    }
  ]
}
```

So i tried to [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?retiredLocale=it) both `stack` lists and assign the result to one of the routers, in this way:

`index.js`

```
const authRouter = require("./auth.routes");
const utilsRouter = require("./utils.routes");

authRouter["stack"] = authRouter.stack.concat(utilsRouter.stack);

var router = authRouter;

module.exports = router;
```

`app.js`

```
var apiRoutes = require("./routes/index");

app.use(subdomain("api", apiRoutes));
```

My routes are very simple and this way everything is working fine for me. However i believe this is not the best way to do it, so if someone has a easier solution, you're welcome.

Lastly, in my objects, parameters like, for example, `params` or `_params`, are empty. In different circumstances they could not be empty, so if someone plans to use my solution i advice to print both objects and check if there are more parameters that need to be worked.